# Targeting an open outlook email for population (Outlook 2010)

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I've been trying to improve the "quality of life" for a follow-up email process in the office with a userform+vba snippet, and I've hit a roadblock in that while I've been able to create a *brand new* email and format it with all the good stuff like **.Body, .Attachments.Add, .To, etc.**, I haven't been able to figure out how to reply to an already-existing email, which is a necessary part of this follow-up process.

I saw [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658940/reply-to-an-open-outlook-mail-from-an-external-program) that gave a solution for C#/vb.net, and in using the Object Browser I found that a "Application.ActiveExplorer" exists in VBA as well. This is what I'm currently working with:

> ```
> Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
> Dim msg As String
> Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
>
> Set followUp = objMsg.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
> With followUp
>
> ' Compose message
> msg = "Good Morning," & "<br />" & "<br />"
> msg = msg & "This is a follow-up request for the following outstanding subjectivities: " & "<br />" & "<br />"
>
> For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
>     If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
>     Counter = Counter + 1
> msg = msg & ListBox1.List(i) & "<br />"
>
> Else: If Counter = 0 Then msg = msg & “nothing”
> End If
> Next
>
> msg = msg & "<br />" & "If these are not submitted within 3 days, a Notice of Cancellation will be sent." & _
> "Please let us know if you have any questions or concerns." & "<br />" & "<br />"
>
>     .Reply
>     .HTMLBody = msg
>     ' .Attachments.Add (" ")
>     Unload subjectivitiesSelection
>     .Display
> End With 
> End Sub
> ```

The end goal is just to populate a response message so the user can just append the appropriate user signature and send it off, nothing fancy or automated but something that just makes life a little easier and working a little faster. I've got other things to address in this project (example: hitting OK without selecting any of the predetermined factors would *probably* still build the email regardless) as I go on but this is probably the biggest obstacle in my path.

I apologize if this isn't up to standards or if there's anything missing/unclear, I'm just yet another novice looking for some direction; been learning this as I go with the Object Explorer, MSDN, and plain old searching. I'll try to clarify whatever I can if there's anything ambiguous.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MailItem.Reply method - it returns the newly created MailItem object. Your code above does not make much sense - objMsg variable is not initialized and MailItem object does not have the ActiveInspector property, but the Application object does. You might also want to look at the Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection collection: it will contain the currently selected items in the folder. Application.ActiveInspector is only for the messages opened in the active inspector.

Comment: It was exactly as you said: I never initialized what I wanted to use. I will say that I wasn't clear about one thing in my original post; I **did** want to select the currently _open_ email, not one currently _selected_, as my company archives the .msg file in our proprietary system and then opens that .msg file when a "follow up" needs to happen.